# Setting a propery in an .ashx page

Tags: c#, .net, ashx

I have an .ashx component that is used by a couple of pages, and because of a requirement it needs to have a bool-property in order to act differently for one of the pages that is using the component.

What I would normally do is something like [this](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-FAQ/User-Control-Property.aspx) but that is for .aspx pages, and it doesn't seem to work to do exactly the same for an .ashx page.

What I want is to be able to set a bool property via the .ascx page that'll be reflected in the .ashx page.

This is the current code that is not working:

The .ashx.cs page has this property:

```
public bool ShowUnpublishedConcepts
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

That I'm trying to set like this:

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlConceptTree" runat="server">
        <ExtExt:TreePane ID="treeConcepts"
Loader="ConceptTreeLoader.ashx"
ShowUnpublishedConcepts="True">
        </ExtExt:TreePane>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it for me:

```
        Loader="ConceptTreeLoader.ashx?ShowUnpublished=false"
```

And in the ashx.cs page I request the parameter:

```
string ShowUnpublished = context.Request["ShowUnpublished"];
```

Which will equal to false.

Answer (score 3):

ASHX files are not really pages but server side code so they have no view state. You'll need to put the values in session to have them persist.

Comment: Scott Hanselman shows how to use Session in an ASHX file here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingSessionStateInHttpHandlersASHXFiles.aspx